# Showing one-to-many relationships in table form

Tags: tables

Let's say I have 5 values for a table row, and each value has its own paired value. How do I show that in a table format?

Like

```
1234567 + xyz
1234568 + abc
1234569 + abc
1234570 + xyz
```

Answer (score 6):

This is typically accomplished with row or column spanning. If I understand correctly, it would be:
[image: Example table with row spanning]

Is there a reason it has to be a table? Can you give more context for your use case?